# Gap issue for CSS sticky header (mobile device only)

Tags: css, position, sticky

I'm using CSS position sticky for floating header, some of the mobile device  will display a small gap while scrolling, around 1px in between "element_b" and "element_c"

```
#element_a{
    width: 100%;
    position: -webkit-sticky !important;
    position: sticky !important;
    top: 0;
}
#element_b{
    width: 100%;
    position: -webkit-sticky !important;
    position: sticky !important;
}

<script>
   $("#element_b").css("top", $('#element_a').height());
</script>

<div id="element_a">Sticky header A</div>
<div id="element_b">Sticky header B</div>
<div id="element_c">Content After Sticky header C</div>
```

Anyone have idea on this? thank you

Comment: Are you use CSS media queries? Maybe it will help you.

Comment: may i know which portion should use media queries?

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries for that, if you have a small gap i.e 1px then you can use CSS media query for, #element_c and pull up by -1px. Because according to your code you can apply any CSS code to #element_c.
I am posting a screen size for reference, in which screen size you faced the problem you write the code according to that.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  #element_c {
    margin-top:-1px;
  }
}
```

Comment: i downvoted this by error and can't reupvote it, weird vote system, this simple fix is really useful, margin-top -Xpx is the way to go for the gap issue